# web scrapping node js using puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping

Hey guys I am beginner with scrapping things then I have this code it is using document.queryselectAll to select images from website...then I am getting different quantity of imgs from the website... I mean in the console I can get 12 imgs but when I run the scrapper it is getting more then this 64 imgs... I think it is getting all the images from the all blog but I just want images from the url asked.

```
//importing the library
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const fs = require("fs");


(async () => {

    try{

    const brower = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await brower.newPage();

    //defining the url to go to
    await page.goto(("https://www.orcawise.com/blogs/blog-what-is-the-use-of-jwt"), {
        waitUntil: 'load'
    });



    

    const imgList = await page.evaluate(() => {

        const nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

        const imgArray = [...nodeList]

        const imgList = imgArray.map( img => ({src: img.src}));

        return imgList;

        

     });

     //import imgList to jason

     fs.writeFile("listUrl.json", JSON.stringify(imgList, null, 2), err => {
        if(err) throw new Error("something wrong");
        console.log("sucessfull");
     })

     

           
   
   await brower.close();
} catch(error){
    console.log("error");
}
})();
```

I have tried to change document.queryselectorAll to selector but it just got the first image.

Comment: where is `document` defined?

Comment: this document it is from queries the same that I uses to inspect in google chrome